# NestedScrollview won't start from top

Tags: android, android-recyclerview, nestedscrollview

I have a Recyclerview in a NestedScrollview.. everything is working fine except one thig. I have total three view in NestedScrollview First two are LinearLayout then Recyclerview. when i run my app the Activity don't show top two layout it starts from top of the Recyclerview.

How its show my layout:

[image: How its show my layout]

How its suppose to show:

[image: How its suppose to show]

And i am loading this enite layout under a viewpager and my viewpager is a child of Coordinator Layout.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.v4.widget.NestedScrollView
android:id="@+id/scrollView"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:background="@color/home_layout_background">

<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical">

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:orientation="horizontal">

        <com.daimajia.slider.library.SliderLayout
            android:id="@+id/image_slider"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="@dimen/image_slider_height"
            android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/image_slider_top_margin" />
    </LinearLayout>

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginLeft="@dimen/popular_fragment_side_padding"
        android:layout_marginRight="@dimen/popular_fragment_side_padding"
        android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/popular_fragment_side_padding"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:weightSum="4">

        <RelativeLayout
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_weight="1">

            <RelativeLayout
                android:id="@+id/free_delivery"
                android:layout_width="76dp"
                android:layout_height="76dp"
                android:layout_centerInParent="true"
                android:background="@color/white">

                <RelativeLayout
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_centerInParent="true">

                    <ImageView
                        android:id="@+id/btnImageViewFreeDelivery"
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
                        android:background="@drawable/icon_free_delivery" />

                    <TextView
                        android:id="@+id/btnTextFreeDelivery"
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_below="@+id/btnImageViewFreeDelivery"
                        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
                        android:layout_marginTop="2dp"
                        android:text="@string/free_delivery_txt"
                        android:textColor="@color/popular_fragment_four_btn_txt"
                        android:textSize="@dimen/popular_fragment_four_btn_txt_size" />
                </RelativeLayout>

            </RelativeLayout>

        </RelativeLayout>

        <RelativeLayout
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_weight="1">

            <RelativeLayout
                android:id="@+id/flash_deals"
                android:layout_width="76dp"
                android:layout_height="76dp"
                android:layout_centerInParent="true"
                android:background="@color/white">


                <RelativeLayout
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_centerInParent="true">

                    <ImageView
                        android:id="@+id/btnImageViewFlashDeals"
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
                        android:background="@drawable/icon_flash_deals" />

                    <TextView
                        android:id="@+id/btnTextFlashDeals"
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_below="@+id/btnImageViewFlashDeals"
                        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
                        android:layout_marginTop="2dp"
                        android:text="@string/flash_deals_txt"
                        android:textColor="@color/popular_fragment_four_btn_txt"
                        android:textSize="@dimen/popular_fragment_four_btn_txt_size" />
                </RelativeLayout>

            </RelativeLayout>

        </RelativeLayout>

        <RelativeLayout
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_weight="1">

            <RelativeLayout
                android:id="@+id/for_you"
                android:layout_width="76dp"
                android:layout_height="76dp"
                android:layout_centerInParent="true"
                android:background="@color/white">

                <RelativeLayout
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_centerInParent="true">

                    <ImageView
                        android:id="@+id/btnImageViewForYou"
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
                        android:background="@drawable/icon_for_you" />

                    <TextView
                        android:id="@+id/btnTextForYou"
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_below="@+id/btnImageViewForYou"
                        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
                        android:layout_marginTop="2dp"
                        android:text="@string/for_you_txt"
                        android:textColor="@color/popular_fragment_four_btn_txt"
                        android:textSize="@dimen/popular_fragment_four_btn_txt_size" />
                </RelativeLayout>


            </RelativeLayout>
        </RelativeLayout>

        <RelativeLayout
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_weight="1">

            <RelativeLayout
                android:id="@+id/shake_deals"
                android:layout_width="76dp"
                android:layout_height="76dp"
                android:layout_centerInParent="true"
                android:background="@color/white">

                <RelativeLayout
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_centerInParent="true">

                    <ImageView
                        android:id="@+id/btnImageViewShakeDeals"
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
                        android:background="@drawable/icon_shake_deals" />

                    <TextView
                        android:id="@+id/btnTextShakeDeals"
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_below="@+id/btnImageViewShakeDeals"
                        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
                        android:layout_marginTop="2dp"
                        android:text="@string/shake_deals"
                        android:textColor="@color/popular_fragment_four_btn_txt"
                        android:textSize="@dimen/popular_fragment_four_btn_txt_size" />
                </RelativeLayout>

            </RelativeLayout>
        </RelativeLayout>
    </LinearLayout>

    <android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
        android:id="@+id/recycler_view"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_marginLeft="@dimen/popular_fragment_side_padding"
        android:layout_marginRight="@dimen/popular_fragment_side_padding"
        android:layout_marginTop="18dp"
        android:scrollbars="none" />

</LinearLayout>

</android.support.v4.widget.NestedScrollView>
```

My ViewPager Layout

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
android:id="@+id/main_content"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent">

<android.support.v4.view.ViewPager
    android:id="@+id/viewPager"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="@color/home_layout_background"
    app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior"/>

<android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
    android:id="@+id/appbar"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content">

    <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
        android:id="@+id/toolbar"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:background="@drawable/toolbar_background"
        app:layout_scrollFlags="scroll|enterAlways">

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/toolbar_title"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="center"
            android:text="@string/title_home"
            android:textColor="@color/toolbar_title_txt_color"
            android:textSize="@dimen/toolbar_txt_size"
            android:textStyle="bold" />

    </android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar>


    <android.support.design.widget.TabLayout android:id="@+id/tabs"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="@color/white"
        app:tabMode="scrollable"
        app:tabTextColor="@color/tab_bar_txt"
        app:tabIndicatorColor="@color/tab_bar_txt_selected"
        app:tabSelectedTextColor="@color/tab_bar_txt_selected"
        app:tabTextAppearance="@style/TabTextAppeareance"/>

</android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>



</android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
```

Answer (score 66, accepted):

It is a problem about focus. Try :

```
findViewById(R.id.recycler_view).setFocusable(false);
findViewById(R.id.temp).requestFocus();
```

---

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <android.support.v4.widget.NestedScrollView
    android:id="@+id/scrollView"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="@color/home_layout_background">

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/temp"
        android:focusable="true"
        android:focusableInTouchMode="true"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:orientation="vertical">

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:orientation="horizontal">

            <com.daimajia.slider.library.SliderLayout
                android:id="@+id/image_slider"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="@dimen/image_slider_height"
                android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/image_slider_top_margin" />
        </LinearLayout>

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginLeft="@dimen/popular_fragment_side_padding"
            android:layout_marginRight="@dimen/popular_fragment_side_padding"
            android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/popular_fragment_side_padding"
            android:orientation="horizontal"
            android:weightSum="4">

            <RelativeLayout
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:layout_weight="1">

                <RelativeLayout
                    android:id="@+id/free_delivery"
                    android:layout_width="76dp"
                    android:layout_height="76dp"
                    android:layout_centerInParent="true"
                    android:background="@color/white">

                    <RelativeLayout
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_centerInParent="true">

                        <ImageView
                            android:id="@+id/btnImageViewFreeDelivery"
                            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                            android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
                            android:background="@drawable/icon_free_delivery" />

                        <TextView
                            android:id="@+id/btnTextFreeDelivery"
                            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                            android:layout_below="@+id/btnImageViewFreeDelivery"
                            android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
                            android:layout_marginTop="2dp"
                            android:text="@string/free_delivery_txt"
                            android:textColor="@color/popular_fragment_four_btn_txt"
                            android:textSize="@dimen/popular_fragment_four_btn_txt_size" />
                    </RelativeLayout>

                </RelativeLayout>

            </RelativeLayout>

            <RelativeLayout
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:layout_weight="1">

                <RelativeLayout
                    android:id="@+id/flash_deals"
                    android:layout_width="76dp"
                    android:layout_height="76dp"
                    android:layout_centerInParent="true"
                    android:background="@color/white">


                    <RelativeLayout
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_centerInParent="true">

                        <ImageView
                            android:id="@+id/btnImageViewFlashDeals"
                            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                            android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
                            android:background="@drawable/icon_flash_deals" />

                        <TextView
                            android:id="@+id/btnTextFlashDeals"
                            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                            android:layout_below="@+id/btnImageViewFlashDeals"
                            android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
                            android:layout_marginTop="2dp"
                            android:text="@string/flash_deals_txt"
                            android:textColor="@color/popular_fragment_four_btn_txt"
                            android:textSize="@dimen/popular_fragment_four_btn_txt_size" />
                    </RelativeLayout>

                </RelativeLayout>

            </RelativeLayout>

            <RelativeLayout
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:layout_weight="1">

                <RelativeLayout
                    android:id="@+id/for_you"
                    android:layout_width="76dp"
                    android:layout_height="76dp"
                    android:layout_centerInParent="true"
                    android:background="@color/white">

                    <RelativeLayout
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_centerInParent="true">

                        <ImageView
                            android:id="@+id/btnImageViewForYou"
                            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                            android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
                            android:background="@drawable/icon_for_you" />

                        <TextView
                            android:id="@+id/btnTextForYou"
                            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                            android:layout_below="@+id/btnImageViewForYou"
                            android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
                            android:layout_marginTop="2dp"
                            android:text="@string/for_you_txt"
                            android:textColor="@color/popular_fragment_four_btn_txt"
                            android:textSize="@dimen/popular_fragment_four_btn_txt_size" />
                    </RelativeLayout>


                </RelativeLayout>
            </RelativeLayout>

            <RelativeLayout
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:layout_weight="1">

                <RelativeLayout
                    android:id="@+id/shake_deals"
                    android:layout_width="76dp"
                    android:layout_height="76dp"
                    android:layout_centerInParent="true"
                    android:background="@color/white">

                    <RelativeLayout
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_centerInParent="true">

                        <ImageView
                            android:id="@+id/btnImageViewShakeDeals"
                            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                            android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
                            android:background="@drawable/icon_shake_deals" />

                        <TextView
                            android:id="@+id/btnTextShakeDeals"
                            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                            android:layout_below="@+id/btnImageViewShakeDeals"
                            android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
                            android:layout_marginTop="2dp"
                            android:text="@string/shake_deals"
                            android:textColor="@color/popular_fragment_four_btn_txt"
                            android:textSize="@dimen/popular_fragment_four_btn_txt_size" />
                    </RelativeLayout>

                </RelativeLayout>
            </RelativeLayout>
        </LinearLayout>

        <android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
            android:id="@+id/recycler_view"
            android:focusable="false"
            android:focusableInTouchMode="false"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_marginLeft="@dimen/popular_fragment_side_padding"
            android:layout_marginRight="@dimen/popular_fragment_side_padding"
            android:layout_marginTop="18dp"
            android:scrollbars="none" />

    </LinearLayout>

    </android.support.v4.widget.NestedScrollView>
```

Comment: yes. he is right. just add `mRecyclerView.setFoucsable(false);`. and the reason is [here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/21235114/1710926)

Comment: thanks for this. took a long time searching. I have a similar layout, with a viewpager and a drawerlayout. the strange scroll issue hapenned when I opened the navigationdrawer. now it's all fixed :)

Comment: thanks a lot, it works for me !
i am using daimajia slider and it was causing the recycler view to keep scrolling.

Answer (score 120):

I had the same problem, and I fixed it the following way.

Add `android:descendantFocusability="blocksDescendants"` to the Linear Layout which is the only child of the Nested Scroll View.

This allows the Nested Scroll View to start from the top with minimal change to code.

Comment: This should be the accepted answer, because doesn't change the style of views. while `android:focusableInTouchMode="true"` make view look like if it is clicked.

Comment: but doesn't it block child views from getting focused? This would make the app completely not accessible!

Comment: Should be accepted answer, nothing from above worked. Just a single line did. Excellent

Comment: Thanks a ton for this solution. Had a similar issue, however it only occurs on versions <=8.1.
I have a fragment that basically has a `NestedScrollView` (with a `LinearLayout` as child) inside a `CoordinatorLayout` that sets `app:layout_behavior="@string/bottom_sheet_behavior"`. Sometimes, for instance when the host activity of the fragment was paused and resumed later on, the `NestedScrollView` did not scroll to the top layout of its child (i.e. `LinearLayout`), but was strangely offset. Setting `android:descendantFocusability="blocksDescendants"` to the `LinearLayout`solved my problem :)

Comment: This works, but it causes all child views to be unaccessable. EditTexts cant be selected anymore.

Answer (score 14):

Just add this line to child of `NestedScrollView` in xml:

```
android:focusableInTouchMode="true"
```

Comment: I put a Linear layout inside a NestedScrollView and put every view inside that Linear layout which is a child of parent, NestedScrollView and added android:focusableInTouchMode= "true" in first child of NestedScrollView and it works in my case.

Answer (score 2):

```
<android.support.v4.widget.NestedScrollView
            android:id="@+id/nested_scrool_view"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:descendantFocusability="beforeDescendants"
            android:focusableInTouchMode="true"
            android:fitsSystemWindows="false"
            >

   </android.support.v4.widget.NestedScrollView>


NestedScrollView nested_scrool_view;
nested_scrool_view = mView.findViewById(R.id.nested_scrool_view);
nested_scrool_view.smoothScrollTo(0,0); //set it on top
```

Comment: It's been a while but my solution was "smoothScrollTo(0,0)". It worked like a charm. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I have several EditTexts and a RecyclerView in a NestedScrollView,
So I added this code to my RecyclerView
`android:descendantFocusability="blocksDescendants"`

and now when the screen is opened, the NestedScroll position is always at the top."

Answer (score -1):

Add this line in `NestedScrollView` 's child Layout

```
android:descendantFocusability="afterDescendants"
```