# How to scroll CoordinatorLayout's content to the top?

Tags: android, android-recyclerview, android-coordinatorlayout, android-nestedscrollview

The `ViewPager` has two `Fragment`s,one `Fragment`'s layout contains a `NestedScrollView`, another one's layout contains a `RecyclerView`, when I scroll the `NestedScrollView` to the bottom, here is a demand that user click the whole title region all `CoordinatorLayout` 's content must scroll to top same as the beginning. but I don't know how to do that with `CoordinatorLayout`. it seems that there's no api method that support my demand.

Here is my layout xml:

```
<android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout
    android:id="@+id/coordinate_layout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
        android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
        android:background="?attr/color_26"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content">

        <android.support.design.widget.CollapsingToolbarLayout
            app:layout_scrollFlags="scroll|exitUntilCollapsed"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content">


            <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
                app:contentInsetLeft="0dp"
                app:contentInsetStart="0dp"
                app:layout_collapseMode="pin"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content">

            </android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar>


        </android.support.design.widget.CollapsingToolbarLayout>

        <android.support.design.widget.TabLayout

            app:tabTextColor="?attr/color_8"
            app:tabSelectedTextColor="?attr/color_18"
            app:tabIndicatorHeight="0dp"
            app:tabGravity="fill"
            app:tabMode="fixed"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="42dp">

        </android.support.design.widget.TabLayout>

    </android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>


    <android.support.v4.view.ViewPager
            app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior"
            android:id="@+id/view_pager"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"> 
    </android.support.v4.view.ViewPager>

 </android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
```

Answer (score 0):

> when I scroll the `NestedScrollView` to the bottom, here is a demand
>   that user click the whole title region all `CoordinatorLayout` 's
>   content must scroll to top same as the beginning. but I don't know how
>   to do that with `CoordinatorLayout`

You can handle that when user clicked on the whole title region (Maybe clicking on the custom `Toolbar`'s `TextView`), Reload-refreshing the `Activity`:

```
finish();
startActivity(getIntent());
```

This will make the content start from top just like the beginning.

Or, try this:

```
findViewById(R.id.recycler_view).setFocusable(false);
findViewById(R.id.temp).requestFocus();
```

Check this answer for that: https://stackoverflow.com/a/33584361/4409113

However, you won't need the `CollapsingToolbarLayout` since you just have `TabLayout` and `Toolbar` and there is no `ImageView` or a parallax view in there.

Comment: toolbar must stick to the top

Comment: Check the updated answer. Hope that's exactly what you're looking.

Comment: I think restarting activity is one of the worst possibility for performance, user experience and Android design.