# My ScrollView scrolls to the penultimate position and not to last

Tags: android, scroll, scrollview

I need your hellp for a simple problem, i tried to solve in various ways but no success.
Need my ScrollView scroll to the last position, but he insists scroll for the penultimate displaying 
the penultimate item on the list, I tried the following ways and all exhibit the same behavior:

```
1 - myScrollView.pageScroll(view.FOCUS_DOWN);
2 - myScrollView.fullScroll(view.FOCUS_DOWN);
3 - myScrollView.scrollTo(0,myScrollView.getBottom());
4 - myScrollView.scrollTo(0,myScrollView.getBottom()+1);
5 - myScrollView.smoothScrollTo(0, myScrollView.getBottom());
6 - myScrollView.smoothScrollTo(0, myScrollView.getBottom()+1);
7 - myScrollView.setScrollY(myScrollView.getBottom());
8 - myScrollView.setScrollY(myScrollView.getBottom()+1);
9 - myScrollView.arrowScroll(view.FOCUS_DOWN);
```

I also tried to add a Bottom padding for ScrollView, tried to resize the ScrollView and the same problem always occur. 
Anyone know how I can fix?

Thank you!

Comment: I am finding it very strange, as will adding items ScrollView it rolls down but never shows the last item always penultimate, has researched a lot about and found nothing, the possible solutions that have found the same behavior. Please anyone have any idea?

Answer (score 0):

find out the answer to my question on this link: [Scrollview not scrolling down completely](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14801215/scrollview-not-scrolling-down-completely?rq=1)

This code:

```
myScrollView.postDelayed(new Runnable() {
                    @Override
                    public void run() {
                       myScrollView.fullScroll(view.FOCUS_DOWN);
                    }
                }, 200);
```