# Scroll down after setText

Tags: java, android, scroll

So, what I have currently is basically

```
displayText.setText();
scroll.fullScroll(View.FOCUS_DOWN);
```

This goes over and over with user input, and eventually displayText gets big enough that it moves on to another line, which is why I want it to scroll down.  I'm pretty new to this and so I'm not too sure what I'm doing wrong.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not completely sure about what you want to do, but if I understood well, look at this, it might help you : [How to get the Android TextView to scroll down to the end automatically?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8620153/how-to-get-the-android-textview-to-scroll-down-to-the-end-automatically)